# How to best design my Angular2+ portfolio infrastructure

Tags: angular, design-patterns, web-applications, structure, hosting

I've been creating a portfolio site and don't know how to best design the infrastructure of my homepage along with sample projects.

I'm using Angular for my 3 example projects, but am unsure where to put the code.

These projects are built for nothing more than portfolio pieces for view/use by hiring managers or recruiters.

My question is where to put the code of my project apps in relation to my home page.

---

## Approach #1: A Single App

Would it be best to put them as folders within a single angular app and backend? For example, my Angular code would be structured like:

- src

  - app

    - homePageFolder
    - project1Folder

      - project1Services
      - project1Components
    - project2Folder
    - project3Folder
    - app.component.ts
    - app......etc

An example url with this approach: mysite.com/project1

---

## Approach #2: Separate Apps

Or would it be best to separate them as three separate Angular applications with three separate backends?

Then I could deploy them as subdomains. For example: project1.mysite.com

---

I think it would be easier to manage the all-in-one approach instead of trying to display superior IT hosting skills but am interested to learn best practice here for my case.

Thanks for the help! Let me know if there's any way I can clear up the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Workspace Structure

The best practice is to use a single workspace with multiple projects.

### Single-Project Workspace

Generally, when you first start with Angular and create a new project with the `ng new` CLI command (e.g. `ng new my-app`), you end up with a workspace that supports only one project, and a structure like this:

```
 - src
   - app
     - app.component.ts
     - ...
   - ...
 - angular.json
 - package.json
 - ...
```

... where `app` is the default (and only) project.

### Multi-Project Workspace

What you need to do instead is, create an empty workspace, and after that add each project one by one (as needed).

`new new my-workspace --createApplication="false"`

This creates a blank Angular workspace without any projects.

As you start a new project, you add them to the workspace with this command in the workspace folder:

`new generate application first-app`

This gives you a structure like this:

```
 - my-workspace
   - ...
   - projects
     - first-app
     - second-app
   - angular.json
   - ...
```

Each project/app then has a structure like so:

```
 - src
  - app
  - assets
  - ...
 - e2e
   - ...
```

Refer to this page for best practices: https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#multiple-projects

## Hosting

When it comes to hosting, the layout you mentioned doesn't really map to how you end up hosting your projects (i.e. sub-folder vs. sub-domain). You don't upload the entire project workspace as if it was a server-side (e.g. PHP/JSP) application.

Since Angular applications are SPAs (Single-Page Applications), at the end of the day you build your applications, and you upload static files to a server. There you have an option of serving those static files from subfolders or from sub-domains.